# Можно ли убрать with ... as и for?

Tags: python

Учюсь по книге "Укус Питона" это пятая версия программы для сжатия файла и я всё ломаю голову как убрать конструкцию with ... as и циклы for. заранее спасибо за помощь

```
import os  
import time  
import zipfile

source = ['D:\\static']

target_dir = 'D:\\Backup'

today = target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime('%Y%m%d')

now = time.strftime('%H%M%S')  
comment = input('Введите комментарий --> ')    
if len(comment) == 0:  
    target = today = os.sep + now + '.zip'  
else:  
    target = today + os.sep + now + '_' + \
        comment.replace(' ','_') + '.zip'  

if not os.path.exists(today):
    os.mkdir(today)
    print('Каталог успешно создан', today)

with zipfile.ZipFile(target, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED, True) as myzip:  
    for source_folder in source:  
        for root,dirs,files in os.walk(source_folder):  
            for file in files:  
                path = os.path.join(root, file)  
                myzip.write(path)  
                print(path)  

print('Архивация успешна')
```

Comment: Зачем нужно эти конструкции убирать?

Comment: так как по книге я ещё до неё не дошёл и я не совсем понимаю как это работает так что пока хочу сделать код проще и понятней

Comment: `with` заменяйте на `myzip = zipfile.ZipFile(target, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED, True)` потом в конце `myzip.close()`. `for` лучше ни на что не заменять, лучше изучить сначала его, потом уже продолжать.

Comment: спасибо большое за вашу помощь

Comment: Вы не находите нелогичным убирать \ модифицировать в работающем коде то, что Вы ещё не понимаете? Как Вы замените то, что не понимаете?

Comment: в том то и проблема что код я скопировал со stackoverflow но он был без пояснения и пришлось разбираться самому но увы не получилось

Comment: ну так по книге учишься или скопировал из интернета?

Comment: по книге, но я не смог написать сам поэтому полез в интернет